# Beginner Java - Changing String from First Middle Last to Last, First Middle

Tags: java, string, methods, indexof

Trying to work out a homework problem that demands: 
Changes a name so that the last name comes first.
Example: "Mary Jane Lee" will return "Lee, Mary Jane". 
If name has no spaces, it is returned without change.

After doing some research it seems I can do this with the Split method, but we've not learned that yet.

The thing is I've worked out the code and it seems to work when spaces 
 and a full name is entered, but when there's no middle name or no spaces to separate the character, I get the error:

when the name entered is simply: Harry Smith

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
```

and

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

when the name is Sarah

This is my code, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
public class Names {
    public static String lastNameFirst(String name) {
        int firstIndex = name.indexOf(" ");
        int secondIndex = name.indexOf(" ", firstIndex + 1);
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        String middleName = name.substring(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex);
        String lastName = name.substring(secondIndex + 1);
        String result = "";
        result = lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf` to find the space before the surname.  Then have two different outputs, depending on whether or not a space is found.  You don't need to care about any other spaces except the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using split and a switch would be a lot easier

```
    String name = "Mary Jane Lee";
    String arr[] = name.split (" ");

    switch (arr.length) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(name);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(arr[1] + ", " + arr[0]);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(arr[2] + ", " + arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);  
    }
```

Comment: [Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_picasso) wouldn't (necessarily) be happy if he entered his full name here... (unless he likes going by simply "José, Pablo Diego").

Comment: I think Picasso would be exhausted if he entered his full name _anywhere_.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem nice :)

Comment: Nah, he was know to all of his friends as *José, Pablo Diego*

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh, true, edited the comment just inside the 5m. But my point is: enumerating the cases in a switch isn't going to cover "edge case" names (which are always going to be more common than you think).

Comment: @AndyTurner Yep as a foreigner in Japan I feel the pain

Comment: Yeah, the spec in the question doesn't say that the name has no more than three words.  So "The Very Scary Wombat" would have to become "Wombat, The Very Scary".  The best way to do this is the solution described in my comment on the question, and in Turner, Andy's answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem well maybe the title does?

Comment: Thank you!! I've yet to learn about arrays and split, but will keep this for ref!

Answer (score 2):

A more robust way is to use `lastIndexOf` to find the last space:

```
int lastSpace = name.lastIndexOf(' ');
if (lastSpace != -1) {
  String lastName = name.substring(lastSpace + 1);
  String partBeforeLastName = name.substring(0, lastSpace);
  return lastName + ", " + partBeforeLastName;
} else {
  return name;
}
```

You don't actually really care about the other space (if it's there at all), since the first and middle names stay in the same relative order.

(Generally, there are [lots of falsehoods that programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/); but let's put those aside for the purpose of the exercise.)

Comment: plus one for the link

Comment: Thank you!! Been learning for a week so totally forgot about lastIndexOf

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the input String contains at least two spaces. When that assumption is wrong (as in the inputs "Harry Smith" and "Sarah"), you get an exception.

You must check whether `firstIndex` and `secondIndex` are positive before using their values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code excepts that there are 3 names. It does not handle when there are less names.

```
public static String lastNameFirst(String name)
{
  int firstIndex = name.indexOf(" ");
  if ( firstIndex >= 0 )
  {
    int secondIndex = name.indexOf(" ", firstIndex + 1 );
    String firstName = name.substring(0, firstIndex);
    if ( secondIndex >= 0 ) // we have 3 names
    {
      String middleName = name.substring(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex);
      String lastName = name.substring(secondIndex + 1);
      return lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName; 
    }
    else // we have 2 names
    {
      String lastName = name.substring(firstIndex + 1);
      return lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
  }
  else // have only one name
    return name;
}
```

Should worth trying `lastIndexOf()`, too:

```
public static String lastNameFirst(String name)
{
  int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
  if ( lastIndex >= 0 ) // have at least 2 names
  {
      String firstNames = name.substring(0,lastIndex);
      String lastName = name.substring(lastIndex + 1);
      return lastName + ", " + firstNames;
    }
  }
  else // have only one name
    return name;
}
```

---

Also, could try a different approach, split the name into an array, something like this:

```
public static String lastNameFirst(String name)
{
  String[] parts = name.split(" ");
  switch ( parts.length )
  {
    case 1:
      return name;
    case 2:
      return parts[1] + ", " + parts[0];
    case 3:
      return parts[2] + ", " + parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: I see two compile errors in that last snippet of code.

Comment: Your compiler will tell you.

Comment: Found one: `length` is not a function, it's a property.